# Copy Page URL to Clipboard Javascript Causes Page to Scroll to Bottom

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sharing link that lets the user copy the current page URL to the clipboard for sharing. The javascript works fine, except that when activated it causes the webpage to scroll all the way to bottom of the page.  Is there a way to prevent this?

```
<script>
        function copyToClipboard(text) {
        var inputc = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
        inputc.value = window.location.href;
        inputc.focus();
        inputc.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        inputc.parentNode.removeChild(inputc);
        alert("Page URL Copied to Clipboard");
        }
```

```
<a class="fbtn share share" title="Share" href="javascript:copyToClipboard()"><img src="https://website.com/images/icons/share_small.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `inputc.focus()`, which causes the newly created `input` element to be focused (and thus scrolls it into the viewport):

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var inputc = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
  inputc.value = window.location.href;
  inputc.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  inputc.parentNode.removeChild(inputc);
  alert("Page URL Copied to Clipboard");
}
```

Live example:

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var inputc = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
  inputc.value = window.location.href;
  inputc.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  inputc.parentNode.removeChild(inputc);
  alert("Page URL Copied to Clipboard");
}
```

```css
html{
  height:200%;
}
div{
  margin-top:200%;
}
```

```html
<a class="fbtn share share" title="Share" onclick="copyToClipboard()" href="#">Copy to clipboard</a><br/>

<div>Bottom</div>
```